# Execute when clicking a sign?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want user to run some command when clicking a sign. The current usual solution is using scoreboard `trigger` and detect players with a given score, which is nothing wrong if the sign is easily reachable and there's no necessity to bypass it; However the assumption may not always hold true, and players may trigger the command via chat instead of sign.

How can I make players have to use the sign to run the command?

Comment: Umm... Thanks for this info, I guess. But what's your question?

Comment: @Fabian They want to know how to make a command run when a player clicks on a sign, without players being able to cheat it with `/trigger` in chat.

Comment: It's totally fine if scoreboard is used, I just want user have to click the sign, not directly use command

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in books and tellraw, clickevents on signs can run op commands even if the player clicking the sign normally can't.

The sign clickevent can therefore run your commands directly (e.g: with a `/function`), or `scoreboard players set` a dummy score that is tested elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that :

[Sign Generator](http://minecraft.tools/fr/sign.php)

It's on minecraft.tools, you can write text of sign and enter command that run when the Minecraft user will click on. Generate the command and give you the sign on your Minecraft.